# how to plot particles' trajectory with periodic boundary conditions python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, boundary

I'm trying to plot the movement of many particles with periodic boundary conditions.
I want to plot their trajectory for the last 10 timesteps.

This is my plot code so far (X is a matrix, each column is a different particle and each row is a different time, that gives me each x coordinate at each time; same goes for Y):

```
plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,11))
plt.grid(True)

plt.plot(X[time_steps-10:],Y[time_steps-10:],'k-')
plt.show()
```

But I'm having a problem with the plot because, since I'm using lines '-'  when the particle leaves one wall and reappears in the other I have a line connecting those two postions that I don't want:

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to solve this on the level where you create that matrix, but that is not shown in the question, so it's close to impossible to help here.

Comment: You could split your matrices where the difference between two positions is greater than 6 (almost your domain)